# pretend to have a file without loading it from harddrive

Tags: c#

How to pretend to have a file without actually loading a file? The challenge is not to create a temporary file or load anything from a harddrive. I would rather like to keep everything in "memory".

In memory means to me having an existing class which derivates from stream initalized and having that class working like it loaded a file from harddrive but it didnt...

Comment: A stream cannot be assigned a filename or extension. If you want to have the data and the name together, why not just create a class with a `string Filename` and `string FileExtension` Property plus a Memorystream?

Comment: which derivation of stream allows me to set filename or extension?

Comment: the one you inherit yourself?

Comment: how to pretend to have a file in memory without actually loading a file?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense as asked.  MemoryStreams do not have filenames since they are not files.  You have some problem that you are trying to solve that requires a file name, but have not told us what it is.  Without explaining your root problem we cannot give you a meaningful answer.   http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: What do you mean by "have a file in memory"?

Comment: If you never go to save your data to a file, why would you need a filename?

Comment: having a file in memory means having an existing class which derivates from stream initalized in memory and having that class working like it loaded a file from harddrive but it didnt...

Comment: If you want to pretend it loaded from a harddrive without using one, create a ramdisk (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive) where you load or store files. The files will always remain in the ram and never touch bytes on the disk - you will be able to access it just like a normal harddisk and consequently you can make use of the same classes.

Answer (score 3):

A memory stream isn't a file. It's just data. The concept of setting a filename and extension on a memory stream simply doesn't make sense - any more than it would for a `byte[]`.

Comment: How about a FileStream without loading the file? The point is not class MemoryStream but the idea behind not saving a file just to set its filename or extension

Comment: FileStream is still just a stream (class) not a file. For example: FileStream fs = File.Create(path);  It's File, not FileStream that creates the file itself

Comment: which derivation of stream allows me to set filename or extension? without storing the file on harddrive and loading it?

Comment: @devhedgehog: None of them, because that's not what a stream is about. You could create your own class which combines a stream and a filename, of course. It doesn't help that you haven't said *anything* about what you're trying to do with this.

Comment: why is so much important what i am about to do. I wanna marry a stream with filename thereeeeee

Comment: @devhedgehog: So create a class with two fields: `string filename; Stream stream;`. There. That does everything you've asked for - if it doesn't work for what you're actually trying to do, that's because you haven't told us what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subclass to keep track of the filename, like so

```
class MemoryStreamWithFile: MemoryStream
{
    public string Filename { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i need already existing class and not my own. :)

Comment: Why can't you write your own class?

Comment: I edited my question take a look again pls